# Python issue with linecache reading a line from an external .txt file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm hacking together my first Python project. I'm running the below Python code and having trouble with the linecache.getline. I want it to open the stoarage.txt file. Check if the number is 0. If it is, change it to 1 - play the music and turn on the LED. Then switch it to 2 it doesn't play the music again every time I power off and start up my Raspberry Pi. Any suggestions would be super amazing.

My storage.txt is ending up like this:

```
0

0

0
```

I thought it should look like this:

```
2
0
0
```

My python code looks like this:

```
import requests
import pygame
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import linecache


pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('chaching.wav')


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#Im using pin 23 for the led. 
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
#Im using pin 4 as a basic switch in replacement for a motion sensor.
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)

#Cleans up the number taken from my php file.
Soup = BeautifulSoup

#Subscriber number
sub_num = 0

#goal one value
goal1 = 93  
#goal1 celebration flag pulled from the txt file. Line 1 of the doc. 
goal1cel = linecache.getline('storage.txt', 1)
goal2 = 100
goal2cel = linecache.getline('storage.txt', 2)
goal3 = 150
goal3cel= linecache.getline('storage.txt', 3)

detectDaniel = 0


while True:
    response = requests.get('http://www.bringyourownlaptop.com/php-test')
    html= response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    num = soup.find('section')
    sub_num = int(num.contents[0].strip())

    # figure out if goal have been reached and set the appropriate goal celebration flag
    if sub_num == goal1 and goal1cel == 0:
        goal1cel = 1

    if sub_num == goal2 and goal2cel == 0:
        goal2cel = 1

    if sub_num == goal3 and goal3cel == 0:
        goal3cel = 1

    # This passed the current status of the goal1cel e.g. 0 not done, 1 current, 2 finished. 
    text_file = open("storage.txt", "w")
    #This added it to the text document with slash n used as a line break. Weve also had to change the value to a string instead of a integer. 
    text_file.write(str(goal1cel)+"\n"+str(goal2cel)+"\n"+str(goal3cel))
    #closes the file. 
    text_file.close()


    detectDaniel = 1

    # checks if celebrations need to happen from goal celebration flags
    if goal1cel == 1 and detectDaniel == 1:
        GPIO.output(21, True)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            continue
        print("Goal 1 reached!")
        goal1cel = 2

    if goal2cel == 1 and detectDaniel == 1:
        GPIO.output(21, True)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
                        continue
        print("Goal 2 reached!")
        goal2cel = 2

    if goal3cel == 1 and detectDaniel == 1:
        print("Goal 3 reached!")
        goal3cel = 2


    print(sub_num)
    print(detectDaniel)
```

Comment: `linecache` i haven't any idea about related module, all line got "\n\r" , what doing your module while raised an `\r` char ? My opinion detect single char on single line(but char can't readable).

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in assuming that `linecache.getline` will simply return an integer.  If you run it in an interpreter, it will return the string `'0\n'`, which is a string.

After you get the line, you're going to need to find some way to simply get the number you want (if they're only ever going to be 1 character values, you might as well just take the first character and do comparisons to characters, e.g. `if goal1cel == '1'`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Kevin. I understand what your saying. I'm still not sure how I'd implement it though. This is really my first start with any type of coding and I've only slowing got this far. If you have time would you be able to show me how you might write it? Dan

Comment: Since all you should care about is the first character of the string, you should be able to say something like `if goal1cel[0] == '1'` (this will return true if the first character in the line is 1).  If you aren't familiar with strings and array indeces, you may want to read some python tutorials, as these are concepts central to using the language and will require basic knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin. Much appreciated.